# What is WebORB for PHP?

Tags: php, flash, sockets, remoting, weborb

What is the [WebORB for PHP](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/overview.html) runtime environment? It supposedly connects Flex, Flash, AJAX and Silverlight clients with PHP classes and data from relational databases.

- It seems to support AMF (Flash<>PHP data exchange), is the entire product built around this?
- Does it use sockets? or is it just an AMF service?
- Does it run as a background service on the server? or just on page requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think the entire product is built around that. We use WebORB for .NET where you also have messaging support (I think you don't have that in PHP).
- It doesn't use sockets. An aspx page is used as a remote gateway.
- It doesn't run as a background service on the server. Just page requests.

This is all from my experience with .NET, but I guess PHP will be somewhat the same.

We have worked with Flex-WebORB-.NET-SqlServer2008, but just about anything is possible.